# AngularJS with Restangular is sending cookies automatically

Tags: angularjs, cookies, restangular

The problem is, our server, let's say it's under 1.2.3.4 IP address, has administration and client placed in:

```
http://1.2.3.4/admin/
http://1.2.3.4/client/
```

Administration is setting csrftoken and sessionid in the cookies to keep user logged in onto administration. Though my client is running on AngularJS with Rectangular, and I'm using localStorage for this kind of info.

And when logged in onto admin, because it's the same domain name, client also sends that cookie on every request but I don't need that, and in some cases this is making a mess in the behaviour of the client app, e.g. even user is not logged in on client, it still gets information as he would be logged in (cookies are always send and user account is the same as in administration).

The question is, how I could disable all the cookies in my Angular app (Restangular?) so that cookies won't be sent automatically?